# Binary strings of length $3n$ such that for every $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$, there is $k \in [n]$ such that: $(c_1, c_2, c_3) = (a_{3k-2}, a_{3k-1}, a_{3k})$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binary

Find the formula (can be in the form of a sum) expressing, for a fixed natural number $n \geq 1$, the number of all binary strings $(a_1, . . . , a_{3n})$ of length $3n$ such that for every ordered triple $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$, where $c_i \in \{ 0, 1 \}$, there exists a number $k \in [n]$ such that $(c_1, c_2, c_3) = (a_{3k-2}, a_{3k-1}, a_{3k})$.

---

As I understand the problem - I need to find the formula to express the number of binary strings such that for every possible combination of $3$ consecutive binary numbers, it exists in the string and is placed in such way that the last index it ocupies is divisible by $3$.

So we have to place our $8$ possible combinations: $000, 111, 001, 010, 100, 110, 101, 011, $ in the string. Therefore the smallest string possible consists of $3 \cdot 8 = 24$ digits.

I think the answer would be: ${{n}\choose{8}}8! \cdot 2^{3n-24}$. We first choose $8$ triplets out of $n$ avaliable, then we swap those $8$ triplets as we wish. At the end we choose $1$s and $0$s for the remainning digits.

Is that correct? In the statement of the problem they speak about the final expression being in a form of a sum which throws me off a bit.

Comment: Wouldn't all three bit strings qualify?  There is only one triplet and it occurs with its last index divisible by $3$.  Also don't all strings of all $0$s or all $1$s qualify as long as the length is at least $3$?  And a $12$ or more bit string of alternating $1$s and $0$s.  Your approach overcounts the strings because you might have $010$ in positions $1,2,3$ and again $7,8,9$.  You will count it once in the first position among your first $8$ and again in the second

Comment: I don't think so - not all three bit strings would work for every ordered triple $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$. Not even one of them since there are $8! = 24$ ordered triples, so we need at least 24 bits for that to work out. As for the overcounting problem, I think you are right - maybe I need to somehow use the inclusion–exclusion principle. @RossMillikan

Comment: Let the string be $001$.  Plug that into the requirement.  $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$ must be $001$ because that is the only triplet.  Then note that $k=1$ satisfies the requirement.  We don't care about any other triplet because it can't be $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$  I was even assuming that $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ was really $(c_m,c_{m+1},c_{m+2}$ but now I think it really means $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$  That is much easier to handle with coupled recurrences.  Search the site for that term and you will find a lot of information.

Comment: @RossMillikan but why it would be the case that $001$ is the only triplet if we set the total string to be equal $001$? I mean, as I understand the question: $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$ can be ANY 3-digit combination of $\{0,1 \}$ and that has no connection with string $(a_1, ..., a_{3n})$

Comment: Why would that be  the number of surjections from [n] to [8]? Could you explain a bit more? In-and-out formula is the Inclusion–exclusion principle? @bof

Comment: I think I get your point with the surjections

Comment: I think these are called deBruijn sequences.

Comment: @DanielV No, [De Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) are something else. A De Bruijn sequence would contain each $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ just once, and the index of $c_3$ in the sequence is not necessarily a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a devious way of asking for the number of surjections from $[n]$ to $[8]$.

The answer is $8!S(n,8)$ where $S(n,k)$ is the number of partitions of the set $[n]$ into $k$ (nonempty) parts, a so-called [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Alternatively, let $E$ be the set of all maps from $[n]$ to $[8]$, and for $i\in[8]$ let $E_i$ be the set of all maps from $[n]$ to $[8]\setminus[i]$. The number of surjections from $[n]$ to $[8]$ is equal to
$$|E\setminus(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3\cup E_4\cup E_5\cup E_6\cup E_7\cup E_8)|.$$
By [the in-and-out formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) this is equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^8(-1)^k\binom8k(8-k)^n=$$$$8^n-8\cdot7^n+28\cdot6^n-56\cdot5^n+70\cdot4^n-56\cdot3^n+28\cdot2^n-8\cdot1^n+0^n.$$